# How to get the position of selected item in the select box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to return the position of the selected item in the select box not the value:

Here is what I'm trying but I think this could be impossible:

```js
const selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');

function selectClicked() {
    console.log(selectBox.value); // this is the value but I want the position
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" onclick="selectClicked()" size="10">
  <option>0</option> 
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the position of the clicked option *(with as little modification to OP's code as possible)*.

```js
const selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');

function selectClicked() {
    console.log(selectBox.selectedIndex); // position starting from 0
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" onclick="selectClicked()" size="10">
  <option>0</option> 
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>0</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if you are using `onclick` there is not need to define the `const selectBox = ...` as you could get `selectedIndex` from the onclick event handler. OR you remove the `onclick` and then use a proper eventListener for the element ([as shown in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66373291/2008111))

Comment: @caramba I just tried to modify the OP's code as little as possible to get the selected index. Aside from the part that actually answers the question, your other suggestions are comments on the OP's code, not really an integral part of making this code work as intended.
Still, I'll add a note that my answer is done with the least amount of modifications necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want the `value` or the `selected index` or just the `text` of the selected item. Following will cover them all. See comments in code

```js
document.getElementById('selectBox').addEventListener(
    'change', // you need to listen on "change" event not "click" event
    function(event) {
        console.log(
            'selectedIndex: ' + event.target.selectedIndex, // it's zero indexed, which means the first item will be 0
            ' | value: ' + event.target.value,
            ' | text: ' + this.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text
        );
    }
);
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" size="10">
  <option value="zero">ZERO</option> 
  <option value="one">ONE</option> 
  <option value="two">TWO</option> 
  <option value="three">THREE</option> 
  <option value="four">FOUR</option> 
  <option value="five">FIVE</option> 
</select>
```